# Can not run "egrep" while building maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to run the project to schedule task on Spring Cloud Data Flow local
I met this error while building maven project:

```
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
            java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "egrep" (in directory "D:\Application\WorkspaceReleaseNeon\spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

                    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
            Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
                    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:331)
                    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
                    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
                    ... 19 more
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "egrep" (in directory "D:\Application\WorkspaceReleaseNeon\spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
                    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
                    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
                    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
                    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
                    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
                    ... 29 more
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-scheduler-quartz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-scheduler-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-scheduler-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <signature>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                        <artifactId>java18</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </signature>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This problem might be caused by: spring-cloud-scheduler-parent
Are these any way to fix this problem? Can I replace parent tag with spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: There are two things first: `CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`...and furthermore this is not the pom you are using cause the error log shows that you are using exec-maven-plugin or you have called it directly via goal  ? I don't know why you need to use exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: I just install maven in eclipse to build jar file